# How to get the first number in a string using sed with 'sh'

Tags: parsing, sed, sh, token, line

I am trying to get the number of lines in a file. 
I am using:

*wc -l Example.master | sed 's/.*\([0-9]+\).*/\1/'*

This doesn't work for me, but I would have thought it should. It is not matching. In my case, the file is 5 lines long so I just get:

```
  *5    Example.master*
```

However, the following -does- work (but isn't correct in general because the file could of course be more than 9 lines long):

*c -l Example.master | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\).*/\1/'*

This works and prints out:

*5*

I want to have this work with 'sh' and not have to use 'bash'. Alternates would be fine but I'd like to understand why I can't use [0-9]+ :(

Comment: try `wc -l Example.master | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: For `+` to work, you need to specify `-E`.  Try `sed -E 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'`

Comment: BTW, it's probably easier to just not print the file name by doing `wc -l < Example.master` (pass the data on stdin rather than giving wc a path as an argument)

Comment: That you @WilliamPursell. -E worked great (I should have noticed that in my man page reading!) and using stdin is a nice solution too.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$=;d' file
```

Or:

```
sed -n '$=' file
```

Both print the line number of the last line of a file.